# Check whether the array contain all element of other array?

Tags: php

I have 2 array , the second array must contain all the element in first array , how to check this ? Thank you

```
For example

array 1: Array ( [0] => Email [1] => 1_Name )
array 2:  Array ( [0] => 1_Name [1] => ) 

In this case it is invalid , as array 2 do not have Email

array 1: Array ( [0] => Email [1] => 1_Name )
array 2:  Array ( [0] => 1_Name [1] => Address [2]=> Email )

 In this case it is valid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and test that its output is the same length:

```
if (count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)) === count($arr1)) {
  // contains all
}
```

For an associative array where keys must also match, use [`array_intersect_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) instead.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing a count on $arr2?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie Shouldn't matter, actually.  The point is just that the intersection of the two is the same as the contents of either the first or the second, and therefore contains an identical set.

Answer (score 2):

[`array_diff`](http://php.net/array-diff) can be useful here.

```
if( array_diff($array1,$array2)) {
    // array1 contains elements that are not in array2
    echo "invalid";
}
else {
    // all elements of array1 are in array2
    echo "valid";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$invalid = false;
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
        $invalid = true;
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($invalid);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's `array_intersect()` like @Michael suggested. If you want to know which element is missing, you can use `array_diff()`.