# Check, if array A contains all items from array B, when both arrays are multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, jagged-arrays, array-intersect

I want to check, if array A contains all the items from array B (may contain others, but must contain all), **when both arrays are multidimensional**, i.e. can contains different variable types.

I've seen a lot (particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523796/checking-to-see-if-one-arrays-elements-are-in-another-array-in-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255500/php-check-if-an-array-only-contains-element-values-of-another-array), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650918/how-to-check-if-one-array-elements-entirely-exists-in-another-array-in-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485905/check-whether-the-array-contain-all-element-of-other-array), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559542/more-concise-way-to-check-to-see-if-an-array-contains-only-numbers-integers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404114/php-built-in-function-to-check-whether-two-array-values-are-equal-ignoring-th), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655687/php-check-if-array-contains-all-array-values-from-another-array), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867315/checking-if-an-array-contains-all-elements-of-another-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267121/php-notice-array-to-string-conversion) as well). I've read PHP doc. Everything, that I checked, fails with "*Array to string conversion*" notice. Especially wen using [`array_intersect()`](http://www.php.net/array_intersect) or [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array-diff).

I'm using *strict error checking*, so notices actually holds further execution of entire script and are something, I don't generally like and want to avoid. Is it possible in this case?

My array A is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => content/manage/index
    [Content] => Array
        (
            [title] => 
            [type] => 5
            [category] => 
            [recommended] => 
            [featured] => 
            [status] => 
            [views] => 
            [last_access_date] => 
            [creation_date] => 
            [modification_date] => 
            [availability_date] => 
            [author_id] => 
        )

)
```

My array B is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /content/manage/index
    [Content] => Array
        (
            [type] => 1
        )

)
```

So, is there any way I can if I can use `array_intersect` on multidimensional arrays containing different variable types without getting notice?

Answer (score 0):

My problem (and question) came out of misunderstanding, what "*Array to string conversion*" notice really means. In my case, it was trying to tell me, that I'm trying to walk **multidimensional array** with functions designed to be used on **single dimension array**.

Understanding that led me to a solution within few seconds. There are many of them here, on SO, but the one given by *deceze* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173705/1469208) looked the best for me. So I adopted it into the form of such function:

```
function recursiveArrayIntersect($array1, $array2)
{
    $array1 = array_intersect_key($array1, $array2);

    foreach($array1 as $key=>&$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value)) $value = recursiveArrayIntersect($value, $array2[$key]);
    }

    return $array1;
}
```

*I adopted it to my project and my way of coding, but all the credits still goes to* deceze *([his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173705/1469208))!*

Now I can find an intersection of virtually any array, no matter what kind of variable types it contain and no matter of, how deep it is (how many subarrays it contains).